# QListWidget itemClicked and itemDoubleClicked - block single click if double click

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlistwidget

So far I have this code, which works fine:

```
QObject::connect(mListWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));
QObject::connect(mListWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));
```

The problem is that every time I double click on an item, the `itemClicked` slot gets executed.

Can I block the `itemClicked` slot if the user double clicks on an item? So just `itemDoubleClicked` gets executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to vahancho for the idea, to use a timer. Here is my solution:

**YourClass.h**

```
private:
    QListWidgetItem* mSingleClickedItem;
    bool mDoubleClicked;

private slots:
    void itemClickedTimeout();
```

**YourClass.cpp**

```
void YourClass::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem* listWidgetItem) {
    if (!mDoubleClicked) {
        QTimer::singleShot(300, this, SLOT(itemClickedTimeout()));
        // use QApplication::doubleClickInterval() instead of 300
        mSingleClickedItem = listWidgetItem;
    }
}

void YourClass::itemClickedTimeout() {
    if (!mDoubleClicked) {
        // do something, listitem has been clicked once
    } else mDoubleClicked = false;
}

void YourClass::itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* listWidgetItem) {
    mDoubleClicked = true;

    // do something, listitem has been clicked twice
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually double clicking on an item produces both `itemClicked` and `itemDoubleClicked` signals: click + click. You can use a timer and check after timeout whether the `itemDoubleClicked` signal occurred soon after `itemClicked`, and if yes, ignore the `itemClicked` signal.

Comment: Is there nothing built in for that? Timer seems like a dirty solution to me.

Comment: @Niklas, I agree, this is tricky, but I am not aware of any built in solution for it.

Comment: I posted my solution. Thanks for the idea